com.hivemq.client.mqtt.exceptions.ConnectionFailedException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security
I am using this particular code to test an MQTT connection with HiveMQ, but I'm struggling to disable certificate validation. I don't want to validate the certificate while connecting to the broker. If someone could help with this, it would be greatly appreciated!

com.hivemq.client.mqtt.exceptions.ConnectionFailedException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

public @ResponseBody GenericResponse testMqttConnection(
      @RequestBody AdvancedMQTTSetting mqttSetting, HttpServletRequest request) {

    GenericResponse response = new GenericResponse();

    /*
     * Initialize the client builder with common settings
     */
    MqttClientBuilder clientBuilder =
        MqttClient.builder()
            .identifier(Utils.generateUUID())
            .serverAddress(
                new InetSocketAddress(mqttSetting.getBrokerUrl(), mqttSetting.getPort()));

    try {
      if (mqttSetting.getMqttVersion().equals(PayloadMqttVersion.VERSION_5_0)) {
        /*
         * Configure MQTT 5 client
         */
        Mqtt5ClientBuilder mqtt5ClientBuilder = clientBuilder.useMqttVersion5();
        mqtt5ClientBuilder
            .simpleAuth()
            .username(mqttSetting.getUsername())
            .password(mqttSetting.getPassword().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
            .applySimpleAuth();

        /*
         * Apply Protocol Specific Settings
         */
        applyProtocolSpecificSettings(mqtt5ClientBuilder, mqttSetting);

        Mqtt5BlockingClient mqtt5Client = mqtt5ClientBuilder.buildBlocking();
        Mqtt5ConnAck connAck = mqtt5Client.connect();
        /*
         * Handle Connection Result
         */
        handleConnectionResult(
            response,
            connAck.getReasonCode() == Mqtt5ConnAckReasonCode.SUCCESS,
            (MqttBlockingClient) mqtt5Client);

      } else {
        /*
         * Configure MQTT 3 client
         */
        Mqtt3ClientBuilder mqtt3ClientBuilder = clientBuilder.useMqttVersion3();
        mqtt3ClientBuilder
            .simpleAuth()
            .username(mqttSetting.getUsername())
            .password(mqttSetting.getPassword().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
            .applySimpleAuth();
        /*
         * Apply Protocol Specific Settings
         */
        applyProtocolSpecificSettings(mqtt3ClientBuilder, mqttSetting);

        Mqtt3BlockingClient mqtt3Client = mqtt3ClientBuilder.buildBlocking();
        Mqtt3ConnAck connAck = mqtt3Client.connect();
        /*
         * Handle Connection Result
         */
        handleConnectionResult(
            response,
            connAck.getReturnCode() == Mqtt3ConnAckReturnCode.SUCCESS,
            (MqttBlockingClient) mqtt3Client);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
      response.setError(true);
      response.setErrorMessage(StringConstants.CONNECTION_UNSUCCESSFULL);
    }

    return response;
  }

  private void applyProtocolSpecificSettings(
      MqttClientBuilderBase<?> clientBuilder, AdvancedMQTTSetting mqttSetting) {

    if (PayloadProtocolType.WS.equals(mqttSetting.getProtocolType())
        || PayloadProtocolType.WSS.equals(mqttSetting.getProtocolType())) {
      clientBuilder.webSocketConfig(
          MqttWebSocketConfig.builder()
              .serverPath(mqttSetting.getServerPath())
              .subprotocol("mqtt")
              .build());
    }

    if (PayloadProtocolType.MQTTS.equals(mqttSetting.getProtocolType())
        || PayloadProtocolType.WSS.equals(mqttSetting.getProtocolType())) {
      clientBuilder.sslWithDefaultConfig();
    }
  }

 

private static SSLContext createSslContext() {
        try {
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");`your text`
            try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("truststore.jks")) {
                trustStore.load(fis, "password".toCharArray());  // Replace with your truststore password
            }

            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            tmf.init(trustStore);

            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
            return sslContext;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create SSLContext", e);
        }
    }


You REALLY shouldn't do this. It basically removes all the protection TLS provides

You can disable it, or can make it always return “true”.
        if (!verifyHostname) {
        System.out.println("Building client to bypass hostname verification");

        clientBuilder.sslConfig().hostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> {
            System.out.println("Not verifying hostname: " + hostname);
            return true;
        }).applySslConfig();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Building client with hostname verification");
    }

Check the full example at https://github.com/hivemq/support-examples/blob/main/clients/hivemq-mqtt-client-tls-demo/src/main/java/com/hivemq/client/mqtt/examples/TlsDemo.java#L93

Answers that essentially contain only a link are generally considered to be poor quality. Once that link dies, your answer will be worthless. Maybe you can [edit] your answer and post example code and keep the link so as to reinforce your example.
